# Finding max value in rows

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to create a dynamic dashboard in Excel for managers to look up which metric that needs to be focused on for a range of companies. The data could look like this table below.

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Metric 1 | Metric 2 | Metric 3 |
| Company 1 | 2.1 | 4.3 | 0.1 |
| Company 2 | 5.0 | 3.2 | 3.1 |
| Company 3 | 4.5 | 1.2 | 0.1 |
| Company 4 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 3.1 |
| Company 5 | 3.8 | 3.0 | 0.1 |
|  |  |  |  |
| Company | *Formula* |  |  |

So for Company 1 etc, I want it to show that metric 2 should be the main focus area, for company 2 it's metric 1 etc.

So far I'm trying to do this by using the index, match and max formulas. However, it's not working.

```
=index(B2:D6, match(B8, A2:A6, 0), match(max(B2:D6), B2:D6, 1))
```

The first part of the match is working correctly, but it's finding the max value for the correct column number that doesn't work. I'm  hoping someone here has an idea of what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
=INDEX(B1:D1,,MATCH(MAX(INDEX(B2:D6,MATCH(A8,A2:A6,0),0)),INDEX(B2:D6,MATCH(A8,A2:A6,0),0),0))
```

[image]

**Addition**:

To get top N metrics use `AGGREGATE`:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$D$1,,MATCH(AGGREGATE(14,4,INDEX($B$2:$D$6,MATCH($A$8,$A$2:$A$6,0),0),COLUMN(A1)),INDEX($B$2:$D$6,MATCH($A$8,$A$2:$A$6,0),0),0))
```

Copy formula to the right as far as you need.

Comment: Thank you! I'm always amazed to see people who know a lot about a topic like this. I don't know if it's possible, but would there be a way to get the top 3 opportunities (or another number)? The dataset I'm working with has over 20, and it would be beneficial to have more, but not all of them.

Comment: @MathiasLaursen In the excel you can try to replace ```MAX``` with ```AGGREGATE``` to get top N metrics, just note that if there are several identical values in the row, the first metric will be returned. I add formula to answer.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IFNA(HLOOKUP(MAX(INDIRECT(
 ADDRESS(MATCH(A9, A:A, 0), 2)&":"&
 ADDRESS(MATCH(A9, A:A, 0), COLUMNS(1:1)))), {INDIRECT(
 ADDRESS(MATCH(A9, A:A, 0), 2)&":"&
 ADDRESS(MATCH(A9, A:A, 0), COLUMNS(1:1))); B1:1}, 2, 0))
```

[image]